# How to remove null, false values from JSON file?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a JSON file with this data

```
{

    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "favorited": false,
    "id_str": "92",
    "entities": {
        "user_mentions": [],
        "symbols": [],
        "urls": [],
        "hashtags": [
            {
                "indices": [0,8]
            }
        ]
    },
    "geo": null,
    "user": {
        "verified": false,
        "notifications": null,
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "FFFFFF",
        "geo_enabled": true,
        "profile_background_tile": true,
        "url": null,
        "id": 278,
        "default_profile": false,
        "lang": "pt",
        "location": null,
        "translator_type": "none",
        "protected": false
    },
    "id": 92,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "created_at": "Tue Oct",
    "is_quote_status": false,
    "text": "This is a vdd",
    "truncated": false,
    "retweeted": false
}
```

How can I delete any key-value pairs that contain null, false and true of this file, using Python?

These values can appear in various level of the data structure.

Comment: Curious that the title mentions "null, false" (i.e. "falsy") values, but the question text says "null, false **and true**". Which is it?

Comment: @KevinJohnson, these steps for example:                                                                                with open(arq_geral,'r') as f:                                                                                                                    
    for line in f:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        dados_tweet.append(tweet)


    for tweet in dados_tweet:
        if tweet["geo"]:
            del tweet["geo"]
It does not remove the 'geo', for example.

Comment: My mistake in the title. @alexis

Answer (score 11):

By decoding, processing the object recursively, and encoding to JSON again.

I like to use [single dispatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) for such tasks:

```
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def remove_null_bool(ob):
    return ob

@remove_null_bool.register(list)
def _process_list(ob):
    return [remove_null_bool(v) for v in ob]

@remove_null_bool.register(dict)
def _process_list(ob):
    return {k: remove_null_bool(v) for k, v in ob.items()
            if v is not None and v is not True and v is not False}

data = json.load(source)
json.dump(dest, remove_null_bool(data))
```

I used `is not False`, etc. to test for the exact objects. Had I used `v not in {None, False, True}` the integer values `0` and `1` would be removed too as `False` and `True` are equal to those values, respectively.

Demo against your sample loaded into `data`:

```
>>> print(json.dumps(remove_null_bool(data), indent=4, sort_keys=True))
{
    "created_at": "Tue Oct",
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [
            {
                "indices": [
                    0,
                    8
                ]
            }
        ],
        "symbols": [],
        "urls": [],
        "user_mentions": []
    },
    "id": 92,
    "id_str": "92",
    "text": "This is a vdd",
    "user": {
        "id": 278,
        "lang": "pt",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "FFFFFF",
        "translator_type": "none"
    }
}
```

Comment: when running, it does not recognize 'dest'.
NameError: name 'dest' is not defined
should this occur in this program? Or was it my mistake?
                                                                                                                        file = open('file_ok.json','w') #file to write correct data
file_data = 'file_data.json' #JSON file with null, false, and true values   with open(file_data,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data = json.loads(line)
        file.write(json.dump(dest, remove_null_bool(data)))
        file.write('\n')
file.close()

Comment: @Rennan, where do you think `dest` would come from? Look at the code, look up `json.dump()`, and you can answer your own question.

Comment: @RennanCéosGleyson I was illustrating; provide your own input and output file objects.