# how to remove Null:[] in Json in Python

Tags: python, json, google-bigquery

I've been stuck in streaming insert .Json data into BigQuery but Null:[] in .json data causes error like this .
[image]
I googled and added some parameters on csv.DictReader parameters but Null data are still there.
Could you teach me how to remove Null: data in .Json . Thank you so much .

[image]

```
def stream_data():
    # BigQuery
    client = bigquery.Client()
    project_id = 'test_project'
    dataset_name = 'test'
    table_name = "test"
    full_table_name = dataset_name + '.' + table_name

    json_rows = [] 
    with open('./test.csv','r') as f:
        for line in csv.DictReader(f,skipinitialspace=False,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE):
            line_json = dict(line)
            json_rows.append(line_json)

    errors = client.insert_rows_json(
        full_table_name,json_rows,row_ids=[row['luid'] for row in json_rows]
    ) //stop making record that has same luid duplicately  

    if errors == []:
        print("New rows have been added.")
    else:
        print("Encountered errors while inserting rows: {}".format(errors))
```

Comment: may this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47041963/how-to-remove-null-false-values-from-json-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding `del[None]`:

```py
with open('./test.csv','r') as f:
    for line in csv.DictReader(f):
        del line[None]
        line_json = dict(line)
        json_rows.append(line_json)
```